# How to add a option in wysiwyg editor so that blocks can be selected as images?

Tags: wysiwyg

Using the Wysiwyg module, we are able to add an image. Is there any way so that I am able to view my blocks in it as well as assign those blocks in any place inside a page?

Comment: [Insert Block](http://drupal.org/project/insert_block) looks interesting and does exactly that, though it's only in dev. There's also [this sandbox module](http://drupal.org/sandbox/dman/1075470) which does the same thing, so it's definitely possible. For the former you'd have to implement the button yourself and link it up to the replacement token; for the latter, it looks like that's even taken care of for you

Comment: If you think about it the process is actually pretty straight forward - writing a WYSIWYG plugin is trivial, and all you'd need is to implement an AJAX callback to provide a choice of blocks to insert. These would be 'inserted' in the form of a token string, and a custom filter would be written to detect those strings and replace them with the block after gathering metadata from the string. Simples :)

Answer (score 2):

Seems you will need to write your own plugin. There are dozens of manuals, like [Creating a CKEditor Plugin with a Custom Dialog Window](http://docs.cksource.com/CKEditor_3.x/Tutorials/SimpleLink_Plugin_Part_1) - this one seems to be good for you, as you might want to have dialog window to allow user select a block.

You will need tips from [this Drupal.org thread](http://drupal.org/node/164799) to

- get list of blocks you will feed to the editor
- make block data avaliable in node.tpl.php via preprocess function
- render the block in a node, probably using [custom created, block enabled text filter](http://drupal.org/node/213156).

Don't forget to consider security issues when deciding who should be able to add what.

Last but not least, publish your module on Drupal.org for future developers.